# How do I make money developing DAPP on ethereum?

Tags: dapp-development, dapps

On Ethereum, any node will get incentives(gas) when it wins a transaction. If I'm a Dapp developer and provide a unique service, how do I make my living out of it. Do I need to specify a gas for the author? or What's other mechanism other than asking for donations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The crypto-futurist answer is that your contract does something useful for people, they send it ether, and it sends a proportion of those ether to you.

The practical answer is that you make silly Proof of Concept dapps for financial institutions, and they pay you regular money.

Comment: "...they send it ether, and it sends a proportion of those ether to you..." Is there a silly PoC for this? :)